# NSLocalizedString with empty comment?

Tags: objective-c, nslocalizedstring

i found this good example to use NSLocalizedString : [What is the second parameter of NSLocalizedString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442822/what-is-second-param-of-nslocalizedstring)

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Save",@"Title of the Save button in the theme saving dialog");
```

.

```
/* Title of the Save button in the theme saving dialog */
"Save" = "Save";
```

But what if the comment in NSLocalizedString is empty ?what does is mean? Will it automatically know where to find the translated word in localize.strings?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is second param of NSLocalizedString()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442822/what-is-second-param-of-nslocalizedstring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is the key into localizable.strings.  The second parameter is a comment meant to assist in translation.  It won't effect the behavior of the application at all, so it doesn't strictly matter if it's empty or nil.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  NSLocalizedString(key, comment) just calls NSBundle's `localizedStringForKey:value:table` and passes the comment as the value parameter with a nil table, the behavior of which is what I describe here.

Comment: Well, look at that! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: who are you talking to in your comments? :) thanks anyway, ok so if the comment in localized.strings is different from the one in the "comment" parameter : would this change something?

Comment: Hah.  Somebody pointed out an error in my original answer, I fixed it, and then it looks like they deleted their original comments.  As for your followup question: there is no "comment" in localizable.strings; localizable.strings is just a table of keys and values.  The comment argument you provide to `NSLocalizedString` has no effect on the strings loaded from localizable.string.

Answer (score 2):

The comment is reserved for the [genstrings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/genstrings.1.html) tool to help someone, who may or may not be technical, translate your localized strings into new languages.