# cell.textLabel.text NSLocalizedString parameters

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield, nslocalizedstring

I am just wondering what the second parameter to `NSLocalizedString` is used for.

```
cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Detail", @"Detail");
```

Comment: I cannot understand your question.  Please state it differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442822/what-is-second-param-of-nslocalizedstring

Comment: @rob, thankyou I did not find that in my searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter to `NSLocalizedString` is a comment used to describe the text such as where it is used. When `genstrings` is used to create the base .strings file the comment helps a localizer understand the context.

Answer (score 3):

The first string in `NSLocalizedString` is what will be printed as the string you want the user to see. This can also be a **key** for Localizable.strings.

The second parameter is like a description, or comment for this string.

You can use the **`genstrings`** command-line utility, which can create the strings file for you by scanning your source code and finding `NSLocalizedString`'s.

**How to use `genstring`**: http://steelwheels.sourceforge.jp/Documents/genstring.html

### Example:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"SomeStringKey",@"An example of how to use this string.");
```

### Localizable.string

```
/* An example of how to use this string. */
"SomeStringKey" = "An Example String";
```