# iOS localization, label with number and word together

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, cocos2d-iphone

i want to localize my game. some of my label is like [@"Score: %i", score], and the score can be any number. so can i still use strings file localization?
this is what i do currently, but a lot of work

```
    CCLabelTTF* bestLabelWord = [Helper createLocalizedLabelWithStringUpperCase:@"BEST" color:ccBLACK];
    CCLabelTTF* bestLabelNumber = [Helper createUnlocalizedLabelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", bestScore] color: ccBLACK];
    bestLabelWord.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0.5f);
    bestLabelNumber.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0.5f);
    bestLabelWord.position = ccp(menuPosX, menuPosY2);
    bestLabelNumber.position = ccp(menuPosX + bestLabelWord.contentSize.width + 5, menuPosY2);
    [self addChild:bestLabelWord z:kZLabel];
    [self addChild:bestLabelNumber z:kZLabel];
```

here i separate @"Score" and @"%i", score into 2 labels (word and number) and place them separately. 
so how can i put them into one label? can i put like "NSString stringWithFormat" in localization.strings file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. It looks like this (uncompiled; hopefully there is no typo):

```
NSString *scoreFormat = NSLocalizedString(@"Score: %d", @"Score format");
NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:scoreFormat, bestScore];
```

---

Your strings file for this in English would be:

```
/* Score format */
"Score: %d" = "Score: %d";
```

---

There is no difference between `%d` and `%i`. They are both specified by the standard. I personally prefer to express that it is "decimal" (vs. `%x` hexadecimal) rather than that it is an "integer" (vs. `%f` float). But it does not matter.

You should include the entire format statement in the strings file. You are localizing the entire format statement `Score: %d`. The rationale for this is to permit languages where the order might be different. For example, if there were a language where the correct translation were `"%d score"` or a language where to make sense you would have to say the equivalent of `Score: %d points` or `Score: %d number`.

If you don't want this kind of localization, and you will always put a colon after the label and a number after that, no matter the language, then you can localize just the label as you were in your original code, or like this:

```
NSString *localizedLabel = NSLocalizedString(@"Score", @"Score");
NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %d", localizedLabel, bestScore];
```

You should avoid calling `NSLocalizedString` with a variable parameter as you're suggesting. This is confusing, and can get in the way of using `genstrings` to create your strings file. That said, the following code is not a problem:

```
NSString * const kScoreLabelKey = @"Score";
NSString * const kPriceLabelKey = @"Price";

NSString *GetLocalizedStringForKeyValue(NSString *key, NSInteger value)
{
  NSString *label = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:@"Labels"];
  NSString *valueLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@": %d", value];
  return [label stringByAppendingString:valueLabel];
}

...

NSString *label = GetLocalizedStringForKeyValue(kScoreLabelKey, bestScore);

...
```

(In Labels.strings):

```
"Score" = "Score";
"Price" = "Price";
```

Things to note:

- I created a separate strings file for this called `Labels.strings`. That way it doesn't impact using `genstrings` and the main `Localizeable.string.`
- I used string constants for the keys. That puts all the strings used in one place at the top of the file, making it easy to audit against `Labels.strings`.

Comment: what should i put in strings file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442822/what-is-second-param-of-nslocalizedstring

Comment: A comment. You can leave it empty if you want (@""). When you run `genstrings`, it will be put into your strings file and make it clearer to the translator what this string represents. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html

Comment: so i copy this line and put "SCORE :%i" = "xxx :%i" in strings file? (%i or %d btw), or just "SCORE" = "XXX"?

Comment: what if i want to make a helper method and input @"Score" or @"Price" etc as a variable, and return a CCLabelTTF? should i use [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@: %i", str, @"Score format"]? note that the stringWithFormat now requires 2 variable, but @"Score format" is comment instead of number

Comment: i've tried %i, and it worked quit well. but the thing is, i have many similar labels in game (e.g., "Price: %i", "Best: %i", "Level: %i" etc) and they use the same font name, color, scaleX, font size etc. so it would be great if i can use a Helper method to pass in string and number and return a CCLabelTTF.