# Standards for comments in NSLocalizedString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, coding-style, localization

How do people write their comments for their `NSLocalizedString`s? Is there a standard guideline that we should follow? For example if I have:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Tap your account to sign in", @"");
```

and my comment is "Text that asks user to sign in by tapping on the account", is this a bit ambigous? Should I leave the comment out if it's pretty much self-explanatory?

Another question is, what if I have a bunch of ProgressHUD that has a text set to LoggingIn, what would be an easy way to sync across my app project that this needs to be localized into `NSLocalizedString (@"Logging In", @"some description");` Is there a tool for performing such tasks?

Comment: Take a look at the Mac app Linguan - from what I've heard it's excellent for helping localise apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter is a comment that will automatically appear in the strings file if you use the **genstrings** command-line utility, which can create the strings file for you by scanning your source code.

The comment is useful for your localizers. For example:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Save",@"Title of the Save button in the theme saving dialog");
```

When you run genstrings, this will produce an entry in the Localizable.strings file like this:

```
/* Title of the Save button in the theme saving dialog */
"Save" = "Save";
```

In your specific example, it's fairly obvious what the comment means, but not the context. You should probably add some context like so:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Tap your account to sign in", @"Instruct user to tap their account to sign in (Facebook account, main game preferences)");
```

That way the localizer knows exactly what button you're referring to.

This becomes even more important for buttons labelled "Share" or some other non-specific label:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Share", @"Label for sharing button on main image editing screen");
```

(This is a modified version of my answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442822/what-is-second-param-of-nslocalizedstring/1442843#1442843)).

Answer (score 0):

Rob Keniger is right. I also would like to add this:
Second param can be used as .. **default value**!!

(NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue does not work properly with genstring, that's why I proposed this solution)

Here is my Custom implementation that use NSLocalizedString that use comment as default value:

**1 . In your pre compiled header (.pch file) , redefine the 'NSLocalizedString' macro:**

```
// cutom NSLocalizedString that use macro comment as default value
#import "LocalizationHandlerUtil.h"

#undef NSLocalizedString
#define NSLocalizedString(key,_comment) [[LocalizationHandlerUtil singleton] localizedString:key  comment:_comment]
```

**2. create a class to implement the localization handler**

```
#import "LocalizationHandlerUtil.h"

@implementation LocalizationHandlerUtil

static LocalizationHandlerUtil * singleton = nil;

+ (LocalizationHandlerUtil *)singleton
{
    return singleton;
}

__attribute__((constructor))
static void staticInit_singleton()
{
    singleton = [[LocalizationHandlerUtil alloc] init];
}

- (NSString *)localizedString:(NSString *)key comment:(NSString *)comment
{
    // default localized string loading
    NSString * localizedString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:key value:key table:nil];

    // if (value == key) and comment is not nil -> returns comment
    if([localizedString isEqualToString:key] && comment !=nil)
        return comment;

    return localizedString;
}

@end
```

**3. Use it!**

Make sure you add a Run script in your App Build Phases so you Localizable.strings file will be updated at each build, i.e., new localized string will be added in your Localized.strings file:

My build phase Script is a shell script:

```
Shell: /bin/sh
Shell script content: find . -name \*.m | xargs genstrings -o MyClassesFolder
```

So when you add this new line in your code:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"view_settings_title", @"Settings");
```

Then perform a build, your ./Localizable.scripts file will contain this new line:

```
/* Settings */
"view_settings_title" = "view_settings_title";
```

And since key == value for 'view_settings_title', the custom LocalizedStringHandler will returns the comment, i.e. 'Settings"

Voilà :-)