# The right way to localize in my application

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization

I've read few tutorials, but each one says something different and I've got really confused. What is the propiret way to localize my application?

some says like this:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome to app", @"Welcome title label");
```

and other says:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"AppWelcomeMessage", nil);
```

And in the Localizable.strings, I need to set like this:

```
"AppWelcomeMessage" = "Welcome to my application!";
```

Is the comment in NSLocalizedString(key,comment) is just a description of the key? or it's important and have an effect on the translation itself? what is the right order?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442822/what-is-the-second-parameter-of-nslocalizedstring, I think it should address your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment in `NSLocalizedString` is for the use of `genstrings`. You can leave it `nil` if you do all your localizations yourself. Otherwise, you should make an effort to add a meaningful piece of information to help the people who do localizations for you. Improving their understanding of the context in which the translation is to be made has direct impact on the quality of the translations that you are going to get.

Comment: so lets say that I have this in the localizable.strings: "MainViewControllerNavigationBarTitle" = "Main Menu"; the title that will be on the NavigationBar will be "Main Menu" and it should be called like this with the NSLocalizedString: NSLocalizedString("MainViewControllerNavigationBarTitle",nil)? is it correct to do so?

Comment: @YossiTsafar yes, exactly, the first argument is the actual key, and the second one is just a comment, but you can see it from my answer anyway.

Comment: @YossiTsafar If you do the translations yourself, it's OK to leave the second argument `nil`. If you have a localizer do translations, you should call it like this: `NSLocalizedString(@"MainViewControllerNavigationBarTitle", @"Main Menu")`, so that the localizers see both the key (`MainViewControllerNavigationBarTitle`) and the meaning in English (`Main Manu`) in the file generated by `genstrings`.

Comment: Another question, if now I set the localization for English, German, Spanish and Franch and someone that use's turkish on he's iPhone, it will not be seen as the key that I gave? meaning: NSLocalizedString("MainViewControllerNavigationBarTitle",nil) and the localizable.strings of english is: MainViewControllerNavigationBarTitle = "Main Menu", he will see the "Main Menu" or the "MainViewControllerNavigationBarTitle"?

Comment: @YossiTsafar If Turkish localization is missing, you should get strings from the default localization of your app.

Comment: how do I set the default localization? because it puts the key where the text should be. if I have: NSLocalizedString(@"SettingsMainMenuTitleLabel", nil); it puts in the settings view title "SettingsMainMenuTitleLabel" instead of like in the english localizable "Settings". why is that?

Comment: @YossiTsafar It looks like you have a Turkish bundle that is missing the key. In general, iOS keeps a list of localizations when you select language preferences (see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072349/non-english-default-language-for-ios-app#comment14418173_4094880) for details). If you do not have a Turkish bundle, your English bundle will be selected.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the comment in NSLocalizedString(key,comment) is just a description of the key?

Yes. If you don't need it, feel free to ignore it (pass in `nil`).

In fact, when writing a lot of localizable strings in code, it starts being annoying to spell out `NSLocalizedString(@"Some Key", @"Some Comment")` every single time. What I generally do is

```
#define L(k) NSLocalizedString(k, nil)
```

and it's suddenly a joy to localize my application.